# how to make image background of text in phaser js?

Tags: phaser-framework

[image]

my Image is the and code is here i want to make nameplate of text. This is scorolble panel.

```
const updatePanel = (panel, content) => {
const sizer = panel.getElement("panel");
const { scene } = panel;
var nameImage, nameText;
sizer.clear(true);
const lines = content.split("\n");
for (let li = 0, lcnt = lines.length; li < lcnt; li += 1) {
    const words = lines[li].split(" ");


    for (let wi = 0, wcnt = words.length; wi < wcnt; wi += 1) {

        nameText = sizer.add(
            scene.add
            .text(0, 0, words[wi], {
                fontSize: 20,
                fill: "#f4b331",
            })
            .setInteractive()

            .on("pointerdown", () => {
                // this.scene.print.text = this.text;
                // this.setTint(Phaser.Math.Between(0, 0xf4b331));
            })

        );



        console.log("new line")
    }
    if (words != '' && content != "Loading...") {
        nameImage = sizer.add(scene.add.sprite(0, 0, "nameplate"));
    }
    if (li < lcnt - 1) {

        sizer.addNewLine();


    }
}

panel.layout();
return panel;
```

};

my Image is the and code is here i want to make nameplate of text. This is scorolble panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const updatePanel = (panel, content) => {
    const sizer = panel.getElement("panel");
    const { scene } = panel;
    var nameImage, nameText;
    sizer.clear(true);

    const lines = content.split("\n");

    for (let li = 0, lcnt = lines.length; li < lcnt; li += 1) {
        const words = lines[li];

        for (let wi = 0, wcnt = words.length; wi < wcnt; wi += 1) {

        }

        sizer.add(

            scene.add
            .text(0, 0, ' ', {
                fontSize: 20,
                fill: "#f4b331",

            })


        );
        if (words != '' && content != "Loading...") {

            nameImage = sizer.add(
                new ScoreBg(
                    scene,
                    0,
                    0,
                    "nameplate",
                    "nameplate",
                    words,
                    "",
                    "",
                    "#f4b331"


                )
                // scene.add.sprite(0, 0, "nameplate"),

            );
            // nameImage
        }
        if (li < lcnt - 1) {

            sizer.addNewLine();


        }

    }

    panel.layout();
    return panel;
};
```